# Analytic versus $C^{\infty}$ example

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity

I am currently reading Loring introduction to differential manifolds. There is something I don't really understand in the example below.

So a function $f$ is real analytic at $p$ if in some neighborhood of $p$ it is equal to its Taylor series at $p$. In the example below, [image]we can see f is analytic right? I mean if we get the Taylor expression of f and evaluate at p we find that the Taylor series of this function is zero, which has the same value as f at 0?

Comment: The Taylor series only valid at the point $0$. It is not true in any *neighborhood* of $0$.

Comment: real analytic at p means that the values of the function equal the taylor series for x sufficient close to p. ... so not only at p but around p

Comment: Every function that has a Taylor series is equal to it at the point that the series is calculated. That's true by definition; the Taylor series is constructed by requiring its nth derivative to be equal to the nth derivative of the function at x<sub>0</sub>. Set n = 0 and the Taylor series at x<sub>0</sub> is required to be equal to the function at x<sub>0</sub>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is that a function $f$ is real analytic at $p$ if **in some neighborhood** of $p$ it is equal to its Taylor series at $p$. In your example, no such neighborhood exists at $p=0$ because $f(x)>0$ for *any* $x>0$.

There is a detailed article in Wikipedia regarding your example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function

Read in particular the section:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#The_function_is_not_analytic

Comment: Thanks so much !! That is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

For $f(x)$ to be analytic around $x=0$ we would need its Taylor series to coincide with $f(x)$ **in some neighborhood of** $x=0$, but this is not the case since the Taylor series of $f(x)$ is the zero series, and $f(x)$ is strictly positive to the right of $x=0$.